# 6-sigma tag too localized?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

Is the [6-sigma tag](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/6sigma) too localized? Someone has just posted a question about it: 
[What is the purpose of Six Sigma?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/410/what-is-the-purpose-of-six-sigma)

Also, if it is a valid tag should it be six-sigma, 6-sigma or what it is now 6sigma?

Comment: Don't worry about synonym tags until they appear. Even if we don't catch them early, when we do, making a couple (or more) tags synonyms is pretty easy (for mods).

Comment: Sometime between then and now the tag went away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wondered the same thing, re: the name, the other day, and I ran a query at data.stackexchange.com to see if any other sites were using it.  That only got me so far (no one was) because I think it only queries non-Beta sites (?).

Anyway, I know that PM SE has a 6-sigma tag.  It would be *nice* that if we used it, it was used consistently across related SEs. Personally, I would have gone for six-sigma in both cases, but I don't have the rep to make those changes.

As to whether or not it is too localized, I don't think so -- but I could be easily persuaded another way.

Comment: good points there.

Comment: 6 - Sigma questions really need to get pushed to PP&PM but that general question should be good for the generic what is 6 sigma questions.

Comment: @Chad It's something I definitely plan to watch.

Comment: I did actually remove the 6sigma tag infavor of the terminology tag since thats what the question was really about

Comment: @Chad Ok; was that a remove one tag, then create a new tag edit process?

Comment: Terminology was already in the list.